# Optical Spectra and the Diffraction Grating

Tags: diffraction

I'm doing a lab where we are identifying different gases by their diffraction spectra.  This what my lab book says:

> Verify and calibrate your spectrometer, by measuring Hg and Ne.
>         Measure 5 or more separate lines for each gas ($j=1,2...5$).
>         For each line, make 4 separate measurements of $\theta$ and estimate $\delta\theta$.
>         Calculate $\lambda$, *presuming* a diffraction separation of $d=1016$ nm.  Now obtain $\overline{\lambda_{j}} \pm \overline{\delta\lambda_{j}}$. Plot $\lambda_{j}$ vs  $\lambda_{j}^{theory}$, and obtain your best estimate of the true value of $d$.

I'm extremely confused please help! how do I plot $\lambda_{j}$ vs  $\lambda_{j}^{theory}$, and how does this help determine $d$?

Comment: You need to look at the relationship between the wavelength of light, the angle it is diffracted at and the spacing of the diffraction grating. Google will find you many articles on the subject.

Comment: To add a bit more context. The position (wavelength value) of the spectral lines is known, so this allows you to determine a relationship between the angle if your diffraction grating and the diffracted wavelength. Once calibrated you can measure an unknown sample an be sure that the wavelength values you determine are correct (once converted from the grating angle).

Comment: To add a bit more context. The position (wavelength value) of the spectral lines is known, so this allows you to determine a relationship between the angle if your diffraction grating and the diffracted wavelength. Once calibrated you can measure an unknown sample an be sure that the wavelength values you determine are correct (once converted from the grating angle).